# How do I color conditionally in a density plot?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

[image: sample]I am trying to make a density plot and mark part of the region based on the X value. The following snippet mostly works but has a weird angled cut-off between regions. How do I fix it?

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.normal(size=1000)})

(alt.Chart(df).
 transform_density('x', as_=['val', 'density']).
 transform_calculate(crit='(datum.val < -1.96) | (datum.val > 1.96)').
 mark_area().encode(
    x='val:Q',
    y=alt.Y('density:Q', impute={'value': 0}),
    color='crit:N'
 )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the area mark tries to interpolate linearly from where the blue and orange region ends to the bottom of the x-axis for each section of the area. If you set `interpolate='step'` you will see that the border is sharp (removing `impute` will improve it for the area). You can try to upsample the data to have the interpolation happen over such a small distance that it appears to be a straight vertical line and the areas look connected, more details in the answer to this question [How to correctly shift the baseline in an area plot to a particular y location and change the fill color correspondingly, in Altair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659737/how-to-correctly-shift-the-baseline-in-an-area-plot-to-a-particular-y-location-a/) .

Another solution is to layer the middle portion on top of the entire density plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.normal(size=1000)})

chart = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .transform_density('x', as_=['x', 'density'])
    .mark_area(color='coral')
    .encode(x='x', y=alt.Y('density:Q')))

chart + (
    chart
    .mark_area(color='steelblue')
    .transform_filter('(datum.x > -1.96) & (datum.x < 1.96)'))
```

[image]